# Solving double integral numerically in python

Tags: python, numeric, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a double integral numerically using areas of rectangles, where the  integral looks like is just a function of two variables (theta and phi).

Here's my attempt so far:

```
from math import*

import numpy as np

N = 100000

T = 100000

j = 1

m = 1

lphi = 0.0

uphi = pi

ltheta = pi/2.0

utheta = 0.0

sum2 = 0.0

def fa(theta,phi):
  fac = sqrt(1.0 - ((sin(theta))**2)*((cos(phi))**2))
  top = -np.sign(cos(phi))*fabs(sin(i)*cos(phi))
  fangular = (1.0/fac)*((pi/2.0) - atan(top/fac)) - 1.0
  return fangular


while m < T:
  thetaa = ltheta + m
  dphi = fabs((uphi - lphi)/T)
  dtheta = fabs((utheta - ltheta)/N)
  sum1 = 0.0
  while j < N:
      phia = lphi + j*dphi
      fun = fa(thetaa,phia)
      Area1 = fun*dphi
      sum1 += Area1
      j +=1
  Area2 = sum1*di
  sum2 += Area2
m+=1
print sum2
```

I'm just a bit worried that the second integral (involving theta) doesn't get updated.

Comment: what exactly is the problem on your code? can you specify a bit more

Comment: Looks like you don't reset your `j` counter before the inner loop. Additionally, the `m+=1` on the bottom should be indented, otherwise you're stuck in the `while m < T` loop.

Comment: It looks like I just solved the first integral (theta), and for the second integral I just used the result of that multiplied by dphi (i.e. I'm not really summing the areas of the rectangles for the second integral)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using [```numpy.integrate```](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html)?

Comment: Maybe add comments for each line in the (nested) ```while``` loops explaining what is intended.

Answer (score 0):

The inner integral (sum1) should be reset to 0 before the phi loop starts. Currently, it will keep accumulating values across theta iterations.

```
m = 1
lphi = 0.0
uphi = pi
ltheta = pi/2.0
utheta = 0.0 
sum2 = 0.0

def fa(theta,phi):
   fac = sqrt(1.0 - ((sin(theta))**2)*((cos(phi))**2))
   top = -np.sign(cos(phi))*fabs(sin(i)*cos(phi))
   fangular = (1.0/fac)*((pi/2.0) - atan(top/fac)) - 1.0
   return fangular

while m < T:
   thetaa = ltheta + m
   dphi = fabs((uphi - lphi)/T)
   dtheta = fabs((utheta - ltheta)/N)
   sum1 = 0.0
   while j < N:
      phia = lphi + j*dphi
      fun = fa(thetaa,phia)
      Area1 = fun*dphi
      sum1 += Area1
      j +=1

 Area2 = sum1*di
 sum2 += Area2
 m+=1
 print(sum2)
```